# how to open large excel file from browser

Tags: javascript, excel

I am using this

```
window.open(`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${ExcelURL}`,"_blank");
```

that is working for small file. that's does not working for large excel file size. So what to do I change for large excel file size

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "not working"? Does it not load? Does it not display properly? What do you mean?

Comment: @ZackyTalib I am getting error like this "Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the 5 MB file size limit."